# How does AWS API Gateway handles custom authorizer timeouts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Let's say an HTTP call comes in API Gateway. The authorizer lambda times out after 6 seconds. Does API Gateway fail the call entirely, or is there a retry behaviour over the authorizer?